# Audio output not working with cli

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-os, alsa, arecord

I am using Raspberry pi OS with raspberry pi 4. I have an application which uses playsound with python to play an audio file created by gTTS library. I am using a usb sound card `card 2` which has a playback and capture devices.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: b1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 1: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 2: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


 $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Camera [USB2.0 Camera], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

It plays audio files when I play an mp3 or wav file from the GUI of raspberry pi.

But when I try to play an audio file from python using `playsound` it is not at all working. I does not throws any error. Also I tried it with `aplay` command from the cli. it shows as if its playing the sound. but no sound can be heared.

I think the error is due to incorrect default device selected. I checked to find `~/.asoundrc` which is missing.

How can I get this fixed? where could be the error?